# Find what Recently took the disk space

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, disk-space

My first post here, I hope I'm doing it right.

So, here's the deal: I have a D: drive that's running out of space (not system drive). It had only 1GB left so I checked what I could delete, deleted several folders and freed 13GB. After that I spent some time doing random stuff, browsing internet for a while, etc., after a couple of hours I noticed that the drive had only 5GB of free space. 8GB disappeared.

Is there any way to find out where the space went? Find recent files that occupied it or what else happened. Not just see what takes the space at the moment but determine where the recent 8GB went.

I tried to get some clue with the help of **WinDirStat** but failed to find what changed, unfortunately I didn't save the previous report.

It's not the browser cache, deleted it, no effect. It's not the pagefile or hiberfil, they're not on this drive. Recycle bin is empty. I cleaned the temp files using the default windows cleanup tool, it gave me 1 extra GB, so it's probably not temp files. I didn't download anything, at least intentionally.
Is there a way to identify what exactly stole those 8GB?

Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: We cannot tell you. You will need to do a before and after of the disk usage. But then you'd know what was using the space.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing a search for * (which should return every file and folder) then sorting the results by "date created" or "date modified"?

If there are too many results, you should be able to filter them by file size.

Comment: Well yeah, I might try that, thanks for the suggestion. I wonder how will it go on the 3TB HDD though... :)